# $(window).height() returns document height (but doctype is declared)

Tags: javascript, jquery, doctype

I'm having this problem. I need to get the browser's window height, but `$(window).height()` returns much bigger numer, probably the document height. I have been using this document structure for years. Is there something wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs" dir="ltr">
<head>
...
```

What would be the cause?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I have found where the error was. My text editor (PSPad) automatically enabled option of inserting **UTF8 BOM at start of files**. This leads to invisible characters before doctype. This gave me a hard time once before. But it was more visible back then. It took me two days to find out why is something wrong (images on page disappeared) and webkit browsers rendered head tag in body. Total mess. So now it works perfetly with all new versions of jQuery. Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you really have reasons to use XHTML ?

Comment: Have you try `$(document).height()`. If no then try this.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha I think OP doesn't want the height of the document but the viewport height.

Comment: Yes, there ***is*** something wrong with that document structure! (hint: doctype within xml ?)

Comment: w3c validator checked this as OK

Comment: Hahaha w3c validator is so bad.. Dont ever trust them!

Comment: But now I have accidentaly found (really) few XHTML code structures that were exactly like my one. I know XHTML is obsolete (and always has been). Just want you to know it didn't come form my head ;)

Comment: Out of interest, are you saying that PSPad inserted a BOM between the XML declaration and the doctype?

Comment: No. BOM is inserted at start of the file. Webkit browsers interpret this weirdly. In another discuss forum I was corrected that PsPad probalby inserts more than one BOM. People didn't have problem with just one. Here are screenshots of what happened to me https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71224 (not my post)

Comment: Correction: it inserts one. But when you use e.g. PHP, more files are usually combined - and number of BOM increases.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Sounds like it's actually the PHP combining process that's flawed then, since editors really should be free to place BOMs at the start of UTF-8 and UTF-16 files.

Comment: I was told that this option has been added 9 years ago, but it's inconspicuous and no ones compiles it with it. Since PHP 5.4 it's native component, but you have to use `zend.multibyte = On`, so no one uses it again, no one knows. Don't ask me any details, I don't much understand it. But I think, that this should be defaulty turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the height of the viewport if you use a more modern header :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

If you really need XHTML, so you should use this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

The doctype element must be the first thing in your document.

Comment: Yes, this is a HTML5 header. But I read that strict doctype should be enough. Is that already deprecated?

Comment: If you put something before the doctype, it's probably ignored. I don't think your current declaration is valid.

Comment: I tried the first modern header. But I get the same result! I don't understand that.

Comment: I have already worked with one HTML5 document and I had no problem with `$(window).height()`. This is an old web, which I didn't want to destroy. Seems, new doctype didn't hurt it, but now there is no possible reason to return document height (I checked it and it really is document height).

Comment: It works with jquery 1.7.2. How is it possible that it doesnt work with 1.8.0?

Comment: I did. It's the same. Works fine with 1.7.2. Weird, isn't it?

Comment: It's not clear why you accepted my answer. But maybe I missed something : Do `$(window).height()` work now with the header I suggested ? Do you need jQuery 1.7 for that ?

Comment: I have found many bug reports, but this seems so crutial, it cannot be true. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12426 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13192 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12388

Comment: @actimel, when you look at the bug report, it really looks like the first header I suggested should solve the problem, even for jQuery 1.8.

Comment: **Solved - solution mentiond at the end of the question**

Comment: lol... here's what I use to detect those files with a BOM : `grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' .`. I don't have PSPad there but I think there is an option to avoid the BOM.

Comment: Yes it is - but defaultly it's turned on. And upgrade also turned it on. Didn't keep my previous setting. I'm done with it... Is there any way how could I use that command on windows? ;)

Comment: You could use cygwin ^^. Seriously I'm sorry but I don't know how you could do that without coding a tool on windows.